# How to convert a simple stream(http webresponse) to bitmapimage in c# windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I try 1000 times, to convert a simple stream (http webresponse) to bitmapimage, but no one tutorial is working in c# windows 8.

Example:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(stream);
image1.Source = image;
```

Thank's for all reply.

**Solution**

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
writer.WriteBytes((byte[])command);
await writer.StoreAsync();
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
```

Comment: Are you certain the stream is coming back with *just* raw image data?

Comment: Yes,but the problem is i don't know the correct methods wich i can do this.

Comment: Excellent! I am glad you found the additional line that was needed to make it work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
writer.WriteBytes(response.Content.ReadAsByteArray());
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
```

Comment: Where you modify randomAccessStream, just initialize?

Comment: the randomacces stream remain 0

Comment: randomAccessStream {Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream} Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream
        Size 0 ulong
        
        writer {Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter} Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter
        ByteOrder BigEndian Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder
        UnicodeEncoding Utf8 Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding
        UnstoredBufferLength 10134 uint
        
        (byte[])e.responseObject {byte[10134]} byte[]

Comment: I see. I suppose the entire response must be received before you can execute this code. I am not sure how to wait until the entire response has been received. Ideas, anyone?

Comment: image {Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage} Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
base {Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage} Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource {Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage}
CreateOptions DelayCreation Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions
DecodePixelHeight 0 int
DecodePixelWidth 0 int
UriSource null Sys

Comment: i try with  InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            writer.WriteBytes((byte[])command);
            await writer.StoreAsync();

Comment: Hey guys response.Content.ReadAsByteArray() is giving error in windows release preview... any idea why???

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
private async Task GetLocalImageAsync(string internetUri, string folderName, 
                                      string uniqueName)
{
    using (var response = await HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(internetUri)
                                .GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                               .CreateFolderAsync(folderName, 
                                        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(
                                    string.Format("{0}", uniqueName),
                                    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                await filestream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```