# Basic authentication with BackgroundMediaPlayer in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, basic-authentication

Anyone know of a way to access an audio file that is protected with Basic auth when using a `BackgroundMediaPlayer` in WP8.1?

I've tried using the `StreamingRandomAccessStream` from  [How to play a video stream that requires authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594659/how-to-play-a-video-stream-that-requires-authentication) but it doesn't work with `BackgroundMediaPlayer`. This is because `SetStreamSource()` needs to be run from the background agent, and I can't use a `HttpClient` in a Windows Runtime Component.

**EDIT (2015-04-13):**
I've now tried using a `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` but it never worked properly because of an apparent bug in the `HttpClient` stack:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/07e551c1-37c0-4bd9-9d98-aa3fc90df974/windows-phone-8-portable-httpclient-causes-outofmemoryexception-downloading-large-file?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required#5eb62907-92cd-4643-8c74-9e6c2a30e464

The [SM.Mono.Net](https://github.com/henricj/SM.Mono.Net) repository has a solution, but doesn't work with files over TLS, which unfortunately makes it unusable for me.

Comment: You should be able to use `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` from a Windows Runtime Component.

Comment: Hmm. Only tried with the `System.Net` client. Will try this again with that one

Comment: Well, I've now tried using a `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` but it never worked because of a bug in the `HttpClient` stack:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/07e551c1-37c0-4bd9-9d98-aa3fc90df974/windows-phone-8-portable-httpclient-causes-outofmemoryexception-downloading-large-file?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required#5eb62907-92cd-4643-8c74-9e6c2a30e464

Comment: Did you try using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`? I do not think the bug you pointed out is in the same HttpClient implementation.

Comment: I tried doing that initially yes, to get the total audio file size.  
Then I used that file size to get the data in batches. Problem was, the player would not play the files, and I got the Overflow exception after some time.