# Audio stream requested using HttpClient doesn't play until file is completely downloaded

Tags: c#, audio, stream, windows-store-apps, httpclient

I'm trying to read an audio stream using an `HttpClient` because I need to modify HTTP headers. The only "working" way I found is the following :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://...");          
Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
IRandomAccessStream content = stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
musicPlayer.SetSource(content, "audio/mpeg");   //musicPlayer is a MediaElement object
musicPlayer.Play();
```

The issue is that the `MediaElement` really starts to play when the file has been entirely downloaded, so it's quite useless for streaming. I need it to play as soon as the stream is received.

Comment: You are telling it to download the whole file before you start streaming in your code.  Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

Comment: You could try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594659/how-to-play-a-video-stream-that-requires-authentication

Comment: I created a converter from `HttpClient` to `IRandomAccessStream`, please give it a try: https://github.com/kiewic/MediaElementWithHttpClient

Comment: ok i'll try it as soon as possible. sorry for late response, quit busy...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the overload of `GetAsync` that takes an [`HttpCompletionOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption.aspx). The default value is `ResponseContentRead`, which means that `stream` will not be available until the content is completely read. Use `ResponseHeadersRead` instead, which means `stream` will be available immediately after just the headers have been read.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://...",
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Comment: it seems to be the solution indeed! thanks! but now i have an error "Cannot use the specified Stream as a Windows Runtime IRandomAccessStream because this Stream does not support seeking" which is true i guess, the stream is not seekable as this is just an mp3 file exposed, but when i do `musicPlayer.Source = new Uri("http://...");` this is working fine. I tried other ways like `IRandomAccessStream content = content.AsInputStream();` but the cast is not possible... do you have any idea how to manage this?